# Magento 2 : Error 500 after installing

Tags: magento2, permissions, file-permissions, magento2.3.1

**[Ubuntu 18.04 / Apache 2.4 / PHP 7.2.17 / Magento 2.3.1]**

After successful installing, magento show blank page. I found following error in apache error.log:

> [php7:error] [pid 29252] [client 127.0.0.1:45454] PHP Fatal error: 
>   Uncaught RuntimeException: Can't create directory
>   /var/www/html/magento/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/ResourceConnection/.\nClass
>   Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection\Proxy generation error:
>   The requested class did not generate properly, because the 'generated'
>   directory permission is read-only. If --- after running the
>   'bin/magento setup:di:compile' CLI command when the 'generated'
>   directory permission is set to write --- the requested class did not
>   generate properly, then you must add the generated class object to the
>   signature of the related construct method, only. in
>   /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Generator.php:135\nStack
>   trace:\n#0
>   /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Generator/Autoloader.php(35):
>   Magento\Framework\Code\Generator->generateClass('Magento\\Framewo...')\n#1
>   [internal function]:
>   Magento\Framework\Code\Generator\Autoloader->load('Magento\\Framewo...')\n#2
>   [internal function]: spl_autoload_call('Magento\\Framewo...')\n#3
>   /var/www/html/magento/vendor/mag in
>   /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Generator.php on
>   line 135

I have set `chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/magento/generated.`
But it's showing the same error. 
Can you help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to give permissions to var pub and generated directories. cd into your magento installation and run following command;

```
chmod -R 777 var pub generated
```

you may also need to run setup upgarade and deploy static files so run following commands too ;

```
php bin/magento s:up && php bin/magento s:s:d -f && chmod 777 -R  var pub generated
```

Comment: Thank you very much. But now I have new error: There has been an error processing your request

/var/www/html/magento/var/report


{"0":"SQLSTATE[HY000] [1698] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'","1":"<pre>#1 Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->_connect() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/DB\/Adapter\/Pdo\/Mysql.php:406]\n#2 Magento\\Framework\\DB\\Adapter\\Pdo\\Mysql->_connect() called at [vendor\/magento\/zendframework1\/library\/Zend\/Db\/Adapter\/Abstract.php:460]\n#3 Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT `store_we...', array()) called at...

Comment: you may not have connected to your db correctly. Enter your db user credentials and correct db in {magento_root}/app/etc/env.php

Comment: Also please accept the answer if it helped

Comment: Thank you very much. It works. Also problem was related with root user's password. I created new user with strong password and magento started!